# Error Build FingerPrint

Tags: android, crash

I have an app live on playstore since last 6 months. I recently encountered 
below crash many times reported by users. Can Anybody explain what it is and how to fix it.

```
*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
Build fingerprint: 'zte/P892T57_MPCS/draconis:4.4.4/KTU84P     /20161104.105951:user/release-keys'
Revision: '0'
pid: 21275, tid: 21275, name: .abc.cde  >>> com.abc.cde     <<<
signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr --------
r0 fffffffc  r1 beea71d0  r2 00000010  r3 ffffffff
r4 7181bd28  r5 00000000  r6 7181bd3c  r7 000000fc
d0  412000003f1a4831  d1  000000003f1a4831
d2  0000000000000000  d3  0000000000000000
d4  0010010200000009  d5  0000001400000038
d6  ffffffffffffffff  d7  0014001400000009
d8  000002d03f800000  d9  000005003f000000
d10 40933c0000000000  d11 00000000430b0000
d12 42a6000043560000  d13 3f0000003f743e08
d14 000000003f743e08  d15 0000000000000000
d16 4024c04ebea52ff0  d17 405ae9cc40000000
d18 0000000000000000  d19 0000000000000000
d20 0000000000000000  d21 0000000000000000
d22 0000000000000000  d23 0000000000000000
d24 0071007200720071  d25 0076007500740073
d26 0000000000000000  d27 0000000000000000
d28 0048004700450046  d29 0049004a004a0049
d30 0076007600760076  d31 0000000000000000
scr 88000017

backtrace:
#00  pc 000218b0  /system/lib/libc.so (epoll_wait+12)
#01  pc 00010697  /system/lib/libutils.so (android::Looper::pollInner(int)+98)
#02  pc 000108c1  /system/lib/libutils.so (android::Looper::pollOnce(int, int*, int*, void**)+92)
#03  pc 0006ae41  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android::NativeMessageQueue::pollOnce(_JNIEnv*, int)+22)
#04  pc 00020dcc  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmPlatformInvoke+112)
#05  pc 00051a4f  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallJNIMethod(unsigned int const*, JValue*, Method const*, Thread*)+398)
#06  pc 00000214  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache (deleted)
```

Thanks in advance. Hope for help from all  awesome coders out there.